# Pandas aligning multiple dataframes with TimeStamp index

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, time-series

This has been the bane of my life for the past couple of days. I have numerous Pandas Dataframes that contain time series data with irregular frequencies. I try to align these into a single dataframe.

Below is some code, with representative dataframes, `df1`, `df2`, and `df3` ( I actually have n=5, and would appreciate a solution that would work for all `n>2`):

```
# df1, df2, df3 are given at the bottom
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# I can align df1 to df2 easily
df1aligned, df2aligned = df1.align(df2)
# And then concatenate into a single dataframe
combined_1_n_2 = pd.concat([df1aligned, df2aligned], axis =1 )
# Since I don't know any better, I then try to align df3 to combined_1_n_2  manually:
combined_1_n_2.align(df3)
error: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I have an idea why I get this error, so I get rid of the duplicate indices in `combined_1_n_2` and try again:

```
combined_1_n_2 = combined_1_n_2.groupby(combined_1_n_2.index).first()
combined_1_n_2.align(df3) # But stll get the same error
error: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Why am I getting this error? Even if this worked, it is completely manual and ugly. How can I align >2 time series and combine them in a single dataframe?

**Data:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'price' : [62.1250,62.2500,62.2375,61.9250,61.9125 ]}, 
                     index = [pd.DatetimeIndex([datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')])[0] 
                     for s in ['2008-06-01 06:03:59.614000', '2008-06-01 06:03:59.692000', 
                     '2008-06-01 06:15:42.004000', '2008-06-01 06:15:42.083000','2008-06-01 06:17:01.654000' ] ])   

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'price': [241.0625, 241.5000, 241.3750, 241.2500, 241.3750 ]},
                    index = [pd.DatetimeIndex([datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')])[0] 
                     for s in ['2008-06-01 06:13:34.524000', '2008-06-01 06:13:34.602000', 
                     '2008-06-01 06:15:05.399000', '2008-06-01 06:15:05.399000','2008-06-01 06:15:42.082000' ] ])   

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'price': [67.656, 67.875, 67.8125, 67.75, 67.6875 ]},
                    index = [pd.DatetimeIndex([datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')])[0] 
                     for s in ['2008-06-01 06:03:52.281000', '2008-06-01 06:03:52.359000', 
                     '2008-06-01 06:13:34.848000', '2008-06-01 06:13:34.926000','2008-06-01 06:15:05.321000' ] ])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your specific error is due the column names of `combined_1_n_2` having duplicates (both columns will be named 'price').  You could rename the columns and the second align would work.

One alternative way would be to chain the `join` operator, which merges frames on the index, as below.

```
In [23]: df1.join(df2, how='outer', rsuffix='_1').join(df3, how='outer', rsuffix='_2')
Out[23]: 
                              price   price_1  price_2
2008-06-01 06:03:52.281000      NaN       NaN  67.6560
2008-06-01 06:03:52.359000      NaN       NaN  67.8750
2008-06-01 06:03:59.614000  62.1250       NaN      NaN
2008-06-01 06:03:59.692000  62.2500       NaN      NaN
2008-06-01 06:13:34.524000      NaN  241.0625      NaN
2008-06-01 06:13:34.602000      NaN  241.5000      NaN
2008-06-01 06:13:34.848000      NaN       NaN  67.8125
2008-06-01 06:13:34.926000      NaN       NaN  67.7500
2008-06-01 06:15:05.321000      NaN       NaN  67.6875
2008-06-01 06:15:05.399000      NaN  241.3750      NaN
2008-06-01 06:15:05.399000      NaN  241.2500      NaN
2008-06-01 06:15:42.004000  62.2375       NaN      NaN
2008-06-01 06:15:42.082000      NaN  241.3750      NaN
2008-06-01 06:15:42.083000  61.9250       NaN      NaN
2008-06-01 06:17:01.654000  61.9125       NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, that is suprising; so the `align()` is unnecessary if I do the chain joins?

Comment: Correct, `join` handles the index logic for you.

Comment: Thank you, out of curiosity: could you just briefly elaborate on when one may need to use the align() then? Because to me it seems join() handles both alignment and concatenation in one go.

Comment: There aren't too many practical cases I can think of, but if for some reason you need to only align the index, you'd save a little time by using `align`.