# pandas align irregular time series with different frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have 3 time series which I need to compare over time. Obviously, they need to be aligned to be comparable. Unfortunately, 2 out of 3 time series are irregular. The other 2 range from 2 to 500k observations per `ID` and day.

The initial time series is available every 300ms and could be left joined with both other time series.

However I have 2 problems:

1. these 3 series I was introducing above are in the format of `ID, time, value`, i.e. constitute each an individual time series per group
2. formulating the join condition i.e. assuming the `LEFT` and most fine granular to be joinable within a window of time as there might not be an exact match

## edit

some dummy data

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
def make_df(frequency, valueName):
    date_rng = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-01-02', freq=frequency)
    ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(date_rng)), index=date_rng)
    groups = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    group_series = [groups[np.random.randint(len(groups))] for i in range(0, len(date_rng))]
    df = pd.DataFrame(ts, columns=[valueName])
    df['group'] = group_series
    return df
df_1 = make_df('ms', 'value_A')
display(df_1.head())
df_2 = make_df('H', 'value_B')
display(df_2.head())
df_3 = make_df('S', 'value_C')
display(df_3.head())
```

code (all not really pythonic):
I was trying some non-equi-join similar to `a JOIN b ON a.group = b.group AND time in window(some_seconds)` in SQL, but this has the problem in case there are multiple records which match i.e. not only the first but all are matched / generate a row.

Also, I trued to group data similar to(spark): `df.groupBy($"KEY", window($"time", "5 minutes")).sum("metric")` but this might be quite lossy.

Then I found (pandas) [Pandas aligning multiple dataframes with TimeStamp index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366021/pandas-aligning-multiple-dataframes-with-timestamp-index) which already looks quite interesting, however only produces exact matches. However, when trying to use `df_2.join(df_3, how='outer', on=['group'], rsuffix='_1')` which also joins not only on (exact) time, but `group` it fails with an error that `pd.concat` is required.

After some more searching I found (pyspark) https://github.com/twosigma/flint which implements a time series join within an interval - however, I have problems using it.

Comment: maybe http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html could be used for this?

Comment: Could you provide some example data and any code you've tried so far?

Comment: Please see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a simple way to do it in pandas - so I resorted to do this operation directly in spark.

Flint was my tool of choice. Initially, flint would not work on spark 2.2, but with my fix here: https://github.com/geoHeil/flint/commit/a2827d38e155ec8ddd4252dc62d89181f14f0c47 the following worked just fine:

```
val left = Seq((1,1L, 0.1), (1, 2L,0.2), (3,1L,0.3), (3, 2L,0.4)).toDF("groupA", "time", "valueA")
  val right = Seq((1,1L, 11), (1, 2L,12), (3,1L,13), (3, 2L,14)).toDF("groupB", "time", "valueB")
  val leftTs = TimeSeriesRDD.fromDF(dataFrame = left)(isSorted = false, timeUnit = MILLISECONDS)
  val rightTS        = TimeSeriesRDD.fromDF(dataFrame = right)(isSorted = false, timeUnit = MILLISECONDS)

  val mergedPerGroup = leftTs.leftJoin(rightTS, tolerance = "1s")
```

I.e. it performs sort of a cartesian join over all the groups:

```
mergedPerGroup.toDF.filter(col("groupA") === col("groupB")).show
+-------+------+------+------+------+
|   time|groupA|valueA|groupB|valueB|
+-------+------+------+------+------+
|1000000|     3|   0.3|     3|    13|
|2000000|     3|   0.4|     3|    14|
```

to remove duplicates distinct is used.

Comment: A pure python answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201618/pandas-merge-match-the-nearest-time-stamp-the-series-of-timestamps, especially https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html looks great.